# Efficient way to join a cached spark dataframe with other and cache again

Tags: caching, apache-spark, dataframe, union

I have a large dataframe that has been cached like

```
val largeDf = someLargeDataframe.cache
```

Now I need to union it with a tiny one and cached it again

```
val tinyDf = someTinyDataframe.cache
val newDataframe = largeDf.union(tinyDf).cached
tinyDf.unpersist()
largeDf.unpersist()
```

It is very inefficient since it need to re-cached all the data again. Is there any efficient way to add a little amount of data to a large cached dataframe?

---

After reading Teodors's explanation, I know that I can't unpersist the old dataframe before I do some action on my new dataframe. But what if I need to do something like this?

```
def myProcess(df1: Dataframe, df2: Dataframe): Dataframe{
    val df1_trans = df1.map(....).cache
    val df2_trans = df2.map(....).cache

    doSomeAction(df1_trans, df2_trans)

    val finalDf = df1_trans.union(df2_trans).map(....).cache
    // df1_trans.unpersist()
    // df2_trans.unpersist()
    finalDf
}
```

I want my df1_trans & df2_trans to be cached to improve the performance inside the function since they will be called more than once, but the dataframe I need to return in the end is also constructed by df1_trans & df2_trans, if I can't unpersist them before leaving the function, I can never find other place to do this, however, if I unpersist them, my finalDf will not benefit from cache.

What can I do in this situation? Thanks!

Comment: A union is a relatively inexpensive operation, because you don't have to shuffle data across the cluster. I think the best solution is to keep the largeDf cached and don't persist the newDataframe.

Comment: But if I need to use the newDataframe a lot of time. If I didn't persist it, it need to do the union again and again. Actually, in my case, it's a loop that will union new tinyDataFrame depend on time again and again.

Comment: Yes, but using a union on a dataframe just changes a reference without doing any computations or shuffles. If you cache/persist both input dataframes it should be the most performant solution. I propose that you run the benchmarks in Teodors answer and see for yourself. Alternative 2 should be the fastest.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks both of you, I think I know the rules now. However, if I return the final result dataframe from a function before doing any action on my original dataframes. I can't find a suitable place to unpersist my cache :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val largeDf = someLargeDataframe.cache
val tinyDf = someTinyDataframe.cache
val newDataframe = largeDf.union(tinyDf).cache
```

If you call unpersist() now before any action that goes through all your largeDf dataframe you won't benefit from caching the two dataframes.

```
tinyDf.unpersist()
largeDf.unpersist()
```

I wouldn't worry about caching the unioned dataframe as long as the two other dataframes are already cached, you won't likely see a performance hit.

Benchmark the following:

```
========= now? ============
val largeDf = someLargeDataframe.cache
val tinyDf = someTinyDataframe.cache
val newDataframe = largeDf.union(tinyDf).cache
tinyDf.unpersist()
largeDf.unpersist()
#force evaluation
newDataframe.count()

========= alternative 1 ============
val largeDf = someLargeDataframe.cache
val tinyDf = someTinyDataframe.cache
val newDataframe = largeDf.union(tinyDf).cache

#force evaluation
newDataframe.count()
tinyDf.unpersist()
largeDf.unpersist()

======== alternative 2 ==============
val largeDf = someLargeDataframe.cache
val tinyDf = someTinyDataframe.cache
val newDataframe = largeDf.union(tinyDf)

newDataframe.count()


======== alternative 3 ==============
val largeDf = someLargeDataframe
val tinyDf = someTinyDataframe
val newDataframe = largeDf.union(tinyDf).cache

#force evaluation
newDataframe.count()
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I know what really happen when I call unpersist, but I edit my question and I still don't know what's that right way to solve the dilemma.

Comment: Had the same issue you now have some time ago, but not found a solution (haven't looked at alternatives too much though). I ended up using persist with a different storage level.
E.g: `val df1_trans = df1.map(....).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)` this data would end up evacuated to disk if you run out of RAM, but also use less RAM space since it is serialized. Also notably, Spark will drop-out cache in a [least-recently-used fashion](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#removing-data).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any efficient way to add a little amount of data to a large cached dataframe?

I don't think any other operation could beat `union`. I did think that [broadcast](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@broadcast[T](df:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) function might help here, but after having a look at the execution plan I don't think so anymore.

That led me to write the answer. If you want to know if your caching has any effect on a query, [explain](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@explain():Unit) it:

> **explain(): Unit** Prints the physical plan to the console for debugging purposes.

With the following example, `broadcast` does not affect `union` (which is now not surprising given it's a hint for joins and other physical operators just ignore it).

```
scala> left.union(broadcast(right)).explain
== Physical Plan ==
Union
:- *Range (0, 4, step=1, splits=8)
+- *Range (0, 3, step=1, splits=8)
```

It's also worthwhile to use **Details for Query** under SQL tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my question is more about the timing to cache and unpersist(), not how to implement union.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just trying to answer the part of the question that is still unanswered here. There is one way to unpersist the `df1_trans` and `df2_trans` from your `myProcess()` function .You can create a temp view of the DataFrames using `df1_trans.createOrReplaceTempView(viewName)` and `df2_trans.createOrReplaceTempView(viewName)`. See the [Dataset API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) for reference. Then, after you do some action on those two DataFrames and you are ready to unpersist, you can do so like this - `sqlContext.table(viewName).unpersist`, where viewName is the name you used to create the temp view.

Hope this helps!